# How to fix async function which returns `undefined`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to return the count from my database. The `count().exec` method returns a Promise. I'm trying to resolve it in order to return the value to the user. But it returns `undefined`.

It seems to me I have well used the async/await pattern, so what is wrong? I can't figure it out.

Here my snippet :

```js
app.get("/blog/page/:pageTargeted", (req, res) => {
  var countQuery = Posts.estimatedDocumentCount().exec();

  // estimate count of document in collecion 
  function estimation() {
    countQuery.then(count => {
      countStringified = count.toString();
      return countStringified;
    })
  } // console.log => successfully returns a value

  // set Data
  async function setData() {
    let countStringified = await estimation();
    return countStringified;
  }

  // send Data
  function sendData() {
    setData().then(result => console.log("result in sendData: ", result));
  } // undefined
  sendData();
});
```

*** Edit *** : it's now works, here's my new snippet:

```js
setData().then(result => { // call an async/await functions chain
  console.log("count in Post.find: ", result);
  console.log("pageTargeted in Post.find: ", pageTargeted);

  if (err) return console.error(err);
  res.status(200).send(result);
});
```

I'm just wondering if I have to wrap all the ulterior process inside my function call. So maybe some refactoring will occur if possible to avoid some hell-type process. Anyway, meanwhile it works, so great, thanks.

Comment: The `estimation()` function has to return a Promise.

Comment: It returns countStringified, meanwhile thanks for the hint

Comment: No it doesn't. The *callback* function you pass to `.then` returns `countStringified`, but `estimation()` itself returns `undefined`.  You could simply stick `return` before the `.then()` call.

Comment: waw, several months I code, first time I discover the "return scope" problem. Hmm, interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your estimation() function returns undefined instead of returning a promise, that is because you return the new string from the callback function.

replace `countQuery.then(...)` with `return countQuery.then(...)`.